# sending and receiving image buffer with express [NODEJS]

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to post an buffer image to my storage server multer , but it doesnt works . Here is my code :

My server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

const multer  = require('multer')
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post('/upload',upload.single('image'),async function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.file)
  res.send(200)
})

const port = 5050

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

My poster.js

```
var buffer = await new Promise( (rs,rj) =>{
     request({
          url : 'domain.com/someimage.jpeg',
          method : 'get',
          encoding: null
      },function(error, response, body){
            rs(body)                 
      })
})

request({
   method : 'POST',
    url : 'http://localhost:5050/upload',
    port : 443,
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' 
    },
    formData : {
         file_name : 'name.jpg',
         file : buffer
    }
})
```

OUT PUT :

```
[Object: null prototype] { file_name: 'name.jpg' }
undefined
```

What am I missing in my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is poster.js ? i could not understand. Why are you using port 443 for non https url 'http://localhost:5050/upload' in poster.js

Although testing following code with api client is working fine and i can get the console.log for same.

```
    const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), async function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

output :

```
    [Object: null prototype] {}
{
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'laptop.txt',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/plain',
  buffer: <Buffer 48 50 20 31 35 53 2d 66 71 32 30 37 31 54 55 0d 0a 43 6f 72 65 20 69 35 20 31 31 74 68 20 47 65 6e 0d 0a 31 35 2e 36 22 0d 0a 38 47 42 0d 0a 35 31 32 ... 418 more bytes>,
  size:
```

468
}

Comment: poster.js send post data to server.js . I have removed "443" in poster.js . But req.file is still  undefined . Could you fix it ?

Comment: Your code is not so clear. i.e. not able to understand your poster.js doing but issue is within that code. you have not provided full code for poster.js file and what do you want to achieve. You must be uploading file from some frontend. You can check with api client like postman.